# Can not access ClickHouse remotely on Ubuntu 20.04 DB::NetException Timeout: connect timed out

Tags: clickhouse

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

**ClickHouse:** 23.7.2.25 (official build)

**Server**: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2695 v4 @ 2.10GHz

I can not connect from outside remotely. Error:

```
$ clickhouse-client --user fridary --host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --port 9000
ClickHouse client version 23.7.1.2470 (official build).   <--- other version of clickhouse, becouse it's remote server
Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000 as user fridary.
Code: 209. DB::NetException: Timeout: connect timed out: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000 (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000, connection timeout 10000 ms). (SOCKET_TIMEOUT)
```

Timeout error 10 seconds. I tried also connect with php by `curl` from other location server, the same error.
Server listens on 9000 port:

```
$ netstat -tulnp | grep 9000
tcp6       0      0 :::9000                 :::*                    LISTEN      11216/clickhouse-se
```

If I change 9000 port to other in `config.xml` like `<tcp_port>9032</tcp_port>`, it does not help.

I played here /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml with `listen_host` and it does not help:

```
<listen_host>::</listen_host>
```

This setting also no results:

```
<listen_host>::1</listen_host>
<listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
```

When connecting, here `/var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log` I don't see any new errors.

I tried to create a new user `CREATE USER chista_SQL HOST ANY IDENTIFIED WITH plaintext_password BY 'Chista@321';` - the same error. Also in `/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml` I added new users and set `<networks><ip>::/0</ip></networks>` - same error connection timeout. With `default` user I also can not connect.

ClickHouse absolutely works, I can send sql queries on localhost.

```
$ service clickhouse-server status
● clickhouse-server.service - ClickHouse Server (analytic DBMS for big data)
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/clickhouse-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-09-08 19:31:54 MSK; 27min ago
   Main PID: 11216 (clickhouse-serv)
      Tasks: 715 (limit: 231829)
     Memory: 1.9G
     CGroup: /system.slice/clickhouse-server.service
             ├─11214 clickhouse-watchdog        --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --pid-file=/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid
             └─11216 /usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --pid-file=/run/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.pid

сен 08 19:31:53 fridary-pc clickhouse-server[11214]: Processing configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml'.
сен 08 19:31:53 fridary-pc clickhouse-server[11214]: Logging trace to /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.log
сен 08 19:31:53 fridary-pc clickhouse-server[11214]: Logging errors to /var/log/clickhouse-server/clickhouse-server.err.log
сен 08 19:31:53 fridary-pc systemd[1]: clickhouse-server.service: Supervising process 11216 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
сен 08 19:31:54 fridary-pc clickhouse-server[11216]: Processing configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml'.
сен 08 19:31:54 fridary-pc clickhouse-server[11216]: Saved preprocessed configuration to '/var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/config.xml'.
сен 08 19:31:54 fridary-pc clickhouse-server[11216]: Processing configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/users.xml'.
сен 08 19:31:54 fridary-pc clickhouse-server[11216]: Merging configuration file '/etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml'.
сен 08 19:31:54 fridary-pc clickhouse-server[11216]: Saved preprocessed configuration to '/var/lib/clickhouse/preprocessed_configs/users.xml'.
сен 08 19:31:54 fridary-pc systemd[1]: Started ClickHouse Server (analytic DBMS for big data).
```

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8123
Ok.
$ curl 127.0.0.1:9000
Port 9000 is for clickhouse-client program
You must use port 8123 for HTTP.
```

```
$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
systemd-r  1429 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4   79064      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.53:53 (LISTEN)
cupsd      1458            root    6u  IPv6   81180      0t0  TCP [::1]:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd      1458            root    7u  IPv4   81181      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:631 (LISTEN)
sshd       1584            root    3u  IPv4   95507      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd       1584            root    4u  IPv6   95509      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
nginx      1604            root    6u  IPv4   46091      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1604            root    7u  IPv6   46092      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1605        www-data    6u  IPv4   46091      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1605        www-data    7u  IPv6   46092      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1606        www-data    6u  IPv4   46091      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1606        www-data    7u  IPv6   46092      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
...
nginx      1682        www-data    6u  IPv4   46091      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1682        www-data    7u  IPv6   46092      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1683        www-data    6u  IPv4   46091      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1683        www-data    7u  IPv6   46092      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1684        www-data    6u  IPv4   46091      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
nginx      1684        www-data    7u  IPv6   46092      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
node       4670          fridary   18u  IPv4   57542      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:45325 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216          fridary   52u  IPv6 3010470      0t0  TCP *:9009 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216          fridary   64u  IPv6 3056942      0t0  TCP *:9005 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216          fridary   71u  IPv6 3049875      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216          fridary   81u  IPv6 3049873      0t0  TCP *:8123 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216          fridary   93u  IPv6 3049877      0t0  TCP *:9004 (LISTEN)
```

```
$ sudo clickhouse-extract-from-config --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --key=listen_host
::
$ sudo clickhouse-extract-from-config --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --key=tcp_port
9000
$ sudo clickhouse-extract-from-config --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --key=tcp_port_secure
Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, Not found: tcp_port_secure (version 23.7.2.25 (official build))
$ sudo clickhouse-extract-from-config --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --key=http_port
8123
$ sudo clickhouse-extract-from-config --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --key=https_port
Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, Not found: https_port (version 23.7.2.25 (official build))
```

```
$ sudo lsof -i -a -p $(pidof clickhouse-server)
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/125/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
clickhous 11216 fridary   24u  IPv6 4402332      0t0  TCP localhost:8123->localhost:55628 (ESTABLISHED)
clickhous 11216 fridary   52u  IPv6 3010470      0t0  TCP *:9009 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216 fridary   59u  IPv6 3269663      0t0  TCP localhost:9000->localhost:55934 (ESTABLISHED)
clickhous 11216 fridary   64u  IPv6 3056942      0t0  TCP *:9005 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216 fridary   71u  IPv6 3049875      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216 fridary   76u  IPv6 4442965      0t0  TCP localhost:8123->localhost:58456 (ESTABLISHED)
clickhous 11216 fridary   81u  IPv6 3049873      0t0  TCP *:8123 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216 fridary   93u  IPv6 3049877      0t0  TCP *:9004 (LISTEN)
clickhous 11216 fridary  104u  IPv6 4495568      0t0  TCP localhost:8123->localhost:58468 (ESTABLISHED)
clickhous 11216 fridary  108u  IPv6 4442967      0t0  TCP localhost:8123->localhost:58460 (ESTABLISHED)
```

```
$ sudo ufw status verbose
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP)        ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (Nginx HTTP (v6))   ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

```
$ sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http /* 'dapp_Nginx%20HTTP' */

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fridary@fridary-pc:~$
```

What is mistake?

Answer (score 0):

I had to open firewall port: `sudo ufw allow from second_server_ip/32 to any port 9000`